# How to indent region in a PyQt TextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit

I'm making a text editor with PyQt and want to have a button that indents a selected region in the QTextEdit.

I've gotten to this signal slot function:

```
    def Indent(self):
        tab = "    "

        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor()

        start = cursor.selectionStart()
        end = cursor.selectionEnd()

        cursor.setPosition(end)
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.EndOfLine)
        end = cursor.position()

        cursor.setPosition(start)
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.StartOfLine)
        start = cursor.position()

        while cursor.position() < end and cursor.movePosition(cursor.Down):
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.StartOfLine)
            cursor.insertText(tab)
            end += tab.count()
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.EndOfLine)
```

But nothing happens when I press the button. Either I'm missing something about connecting these QTextCursor actions to the QTextEdit or this is just not the way to do it.

Does anybody know how to best indent a selected region? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of using whitespace, try using `\t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working for you, but I do not understand `end += tab.count`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test')
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleTest)

    def handleTest(self):
        tab = "\t"
        cursor = self.edit.textCursor()

        start = cursor.selectionStart()
        end = cursor.selectionEnd()

        cursor.setPosition(end)
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.EndOfLine)
        end = cursor.position()

        cursor.setPosition(start)
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.StartOfLine)
        start = cursor.position()
        print cursor.position(), end

        while cursor.position() < end:
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.StartOfLine)
            cursor.insertText(tab)
            end += tab.count()
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.EndOfLine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works. I got this from a Qt forum question, so I'm also not sure what += tab.count is. I'll just edit your answer by adding parantheses to your print statements since they raise syntax errors without.

Comment: @PeterGoldsborough No problem, glad I could help. The print statement was just for debugging purposes, it's not necessary to include it.